# Globally raise IP ARP inspection limit rate on Cisco

Tags: cisco, arp

I am trying to raise the ip arp inspection limit rate from the default rate of 15 on my Cisco 9300 since I am getting to many  `%SW_DAI-4-PACKET_RATE_EXCEEDED: x packets received in xx milliseconds` error messages.

Is there a global command to do it for all access ports, range, or per VLAN instead of each individual port?

What max rate would be a safe amount?

Comment: ip arp inspection limit rate 20

Comment: Safe amount depends on your average CPU load... if your 9300's CPU is usually near 0% you could raise this to 30